# Building a custom Eclipse JDT New Project Wizard?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to develop some project templates for a few common Java projects I work on.

Basically, I want to capture a few pieces of information in an extra Window, on the standard New Java Project Wizard, then do some text replacements on a bunch of template files and add them to the project.

I have hunted high and low for a tutorial on how to do this but it seems like you need to really know your way around the Eclipse Plug-In development stuff to get anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial for customizing the New Project Wizard in Eclipse or a project that does something similar so I can look at the source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Phew I thought I was going mad.  I knew that I had read a good article on how to do this, but couldn't find it.

Here it is on Alpha works.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-custwiz/index.html

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks. When I have this working hopefully I can figure out how to extend the New Java Project wizard rather than creating a new blank wizard.